# read and convert PDF files in a SharePoint library

Tags: vb.net, sharepoint, itext

I researched a lot about this topic, and nowhere achievement with some information on how to do this, usually use iTextSharp, and of course I can read pdf that are on my PC, but look how to read a PDF (or download / or save in MemoryStream). I have always the problem "URI formats are not supported".

someone you know, or whether it has knowledge / experiences? or any senior who says "this can not be done"

Comment: Others have done it before, so it's possible. I haven't done it before, but I'll forward it to people who have so that they can answer the question if they have the time.

Comment: Update: the person I contacted referred to his answer to this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/21894553/itextsharp-update-pdf-catalog-in-sharepoint-document-library